# Tabular does not look like requested

Tags: tables

The code

```
\documentclass{report}
\begin{document}
    \begin{tabular}{|l|l|}
        \hline{}
        A & B\\
        \hline{}
        C & D\\
        \hline{}
    \end{tabular}
\end{document}
```

Looks like this:
[image]

I don't want any more vertical lines under C and D.

And if I take away the first line, so that my code looks like this:

```
\documentclass{report}
\begin{document}
    \begin{tabular}{|l|l|}
        A & B\\
        \hline{}
        C & D\\
        \hline{}
    \end{tabular}
\end{document}
```

A gets moved to the left like so:
[image]

How do I fix these issues?

Comment: For the first question, who told you a atbular must end with a \\? It creates a new row.

Comment: It does not compile without the `\\\`...

Comment: I see. You want to type `\hline`, so you need it, but adding `{}` does create a new row.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Simply use `\hline` instead of `\hline{}` ...

See the following code

```
\documentclass{report}

\begin{document}
\begin{tabular}{|l|l|}
  \hline
  A & B\\
  \hline
  C & D\\
 \hline
\end{tabular}
\end{document}
```

and the result:

[image]

Have you considered to not use vertical lines? Makes better looking tables ...